# Pipe 3 terminal commands

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a task to stop a running process and run it again with the very same command it was run previously with.

In a nutshell, I need to change the configs of the running program and restart it to apply changes.

I have a program.pid file where the application stores its PID. A `ps` program on my setup doesn't have a `-p` or alike flags.

What I want to do is to `ps | grep` by the PID I get by `more program.pid`.

The question is how can I put in the result of the second command into the first as the second parameter of `grep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most shells support `$(command)` or `` `command` `` to use the command's output as a variable. At least in Bash, there is also the shortcut `$(<file)` to read a file's contents without invoking any subcommand at all.

```
grep "$(cat program.pid)"
```

```
pid=$(cat program.pid)
grep "$pid"
```

```
grep "$(< program.pid)"
```

However, there's a more direct way to read command lines on Linux without using `ps` – you can read from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`. The virtual file contains NUL-delimited arguments, which can be read using e.g. Bash's `mapfile` function:

```
mapfile -d "" args < /proc/$pid/cmdline
```

Now `args` contains an array of the individual command-line arguments, which you can use as:

```
myprogram "${args[@]}"
```